# Java split parameter from command

Tags: java, parameters, split

I am trying to split the input from user for example `!stats username`
That command works fine but when user don't write username just `!stats`
my checkers fail and crash `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`

```
if (!Config.str.split("!stats")[1].isEmpty()) {
}
```

Comment: Save the result of `split()` into a named array and check it's `length` before accessing particular elements.

Comment: Its crashing with the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check size of array, if there is no username then Array will have only one element with index 0. You can also check if string is empty after trim to check if command had only space at the end "!stats "

```
String[] split = Config.str.split("!stats");
if(split.length > 1 && !split[1].trim().isEmpty()) {
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.split("!stats");` doesnt give errors

your condition is wrong it is giving out exceptions

```
 boolean condition = Config.str.split("!stats").length<=0 ? false : true;

            if (condition) {
                //your code 
            }
```

maybe you should try it this way